# Why is my Flutter application unexpectedly closing on Windows, and how can I resolve the issue using the log output?

Tags: database, windows, flutter, logging, sqflite

- Error:SqfliteFfiException(sqlite_error: 1555, , SqliteException(1555): while executing statement, UNIQUE constraint failed: chgp1101718245448089600.timeToken, constraint failed (code 1555)
- Causing statement: INSERT INTO chgp1101718245448089600 (timeToken, avatar, nickName, position, uuid, channel, mType, isRead, isOpen, device, isTop, isSendType, isNotifyMessage, isCancelAccountMessage, messageId, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, NULL, NULL, ?, ?, NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, ?), parameters: 16827116990000000, , You, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, {"type":"join","name":"You","nickName":""}}) DatabaseException(SqliteException(1555): while executing statement, UNIQUE constraint failed: chgp1101718245448089600.timeToken, constraint failed (code 1555)
- Causing statement: INSERT INTO chgp1101718245448089600 (timeToken, avatar, nickName, position, uuid, channel, mType, isRead, isOpen, device, isTop, isSendType, isNotifyMessage, isCancelAccountMessage, messageId, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, NULL, NULL, ?, ?, NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, ?), parameters: 16827116990000000, , You, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, {"type":"join","name":"You","nickName":""}) sql 'INSERT INTO chgp1101718245448089600 (timeToken, avatar, nickName, position, uuid, channel, mType, isRead, isOpen, device, isTop, isSendType, isNotifyMessage, isCancelAccountMessage, messageId, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, NULL, NULL, ?, ?, NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, ?)' args [16827116990000000, , You, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, {"type":"join","name":"You","nickName":""}] {details: {database: {path: C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\Release-missing\Release.dart_tool\sqflite_common_ffi\databases\chsf990368034050801664.db, id: 1, readOnly: false, singleInstance: true}}}
- StackTrace:#0      responseToResultOrThrow (package:sqflite_common_ffi/src/method_call.dart:123)
- #1      SqfliteIsolate.handle (package:sqflite_common_ffi/src/isolate.dart:33)
- 
- #2      _isolateHandle (package:sqflite_common_ffi/src/database_factory_ffi_io.dart:95)
- 
- #3      ffiMethodCallhandleInIsolate (package:sqflite_common_ffi/src/database_factory_ffi_io.dart:50)
- 
- #4      _SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.invokeMethod (package:sqflite_common/src/mixin/factory.dart:22)
- 
- #5      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawInsert. (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:549)
- 
- #6      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33)
- 
- #7      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:490)
- 
- #8      DataBaseTool.insertDataToDataBase (package:pc_im/init/database_tool.dart:197)
- - [text](https://stackoverflow.com)
- `

Comment: Please use [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in your question.